# Javascript : I don't know why it iterate 0

Tags: javascript

```
function a (){
    i = 0;
}
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    a();
    document.write(i);
}
```

I expected it would **iterate '0'**. But my web browser doesn't show anything. It just ends up with being trapped in a loop.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Walk though your code step-by-step in the debugger. if you don't know how to do that, then drop everything you are doing and learn right now, starting with a site such as https://developer.chrome.com/devtools. If after reading that, you still can't figure out how to use it, or how to debug your code with it, then I suggest finding another line of work. By the way, what does **iterate '0'** mean? You can't iterate `'0'`. You can iterate **over** a range, or **through** an array. It's going to be very hard to become a programmer without being precise, which includes the meaning of words.

Comment: When you use a variable such as `i` without declaring it with `var` (or in ES2015, `let` or `const`) it becomes an implicit global. Because it is a global, the `i` referenced in the loop and the `i` referenced in `a()` are the same variable. That means that every time `a` is called `i` is set back to zero, so despite the fact that `i++` increments `i` to one, it is always reset back to zero right after that. Because of that `i` never reaches `6` and you get an infinite loop.

Comment: The browser isn't displaying anything because the infinite loop continues to run and never yields to allow the renderer to draw what has been output so far. Since you are just leaning, you should be aware there is a lot of bad/outdated info about JS out there; you might benefit from reading a article I recently wrote about [spotting bad JS tutorials](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/spotting-bad-javascript-tutorials/). Your code demonstrates a couple of the code smells I discus in it.

Comment: Thank you all your suggestions. 
There aren't many good websites I can ask question about javascript in korea. And somehow I found this website and I just aksed it here but now I think I was in a hurry. 

I won't give up as torazaburo suggested but I will keep what he said in mind. 

Speaking of his comment, I don't understand what **Walk though** is. 
Man, **It's going to be very hard to become a programmer without being precise, which includes correct spelling**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are beginner try different ways of coding the same snippet, so you can learn more functionality.

```
    function a (){
       console.log("inside a(): "+i);
       i = 0;
    }
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      a();
      console.log("inside for():"+i);
  }
```

Here console.log() is to print the result in Console of browser instead of printing in DOM.
It is easier way to understand whatever you learn.
[image: Infinite Loop in Javascript]

Answer (score 1):

It is not show any thing because `a()` is called again and each time `i` becomes 0. so it loops again and again.

**Do not run the code otherwise browser will hang**

```js
function a (){
    i = 0;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      a();
     console.log(i);
  }
```

Comment: each time i run the OP code my browser tab hangs and i have to close the tab

Comment: yes it will hang. because it is looping infinitely and  no `console.log()` or anything like that